# Failing to compile the zziplib library with MinGW on Windows 10

Tags: c, lua, compiler-errors, windows-10, mingw-w64

Good day

I am attempting to compile zziplib-0.13.69 (http://zziplib.sourceforge.net/) with MinGW, as I would like to use LuaZip for Lua 5.3.5. I have installed the dependency zlib 1.2.3. (http://www.zlib.net/), which thankfully has a windows installer. In order to create a UNIX environment and make use of the provided make files I use msys.bat, cd to the source directory and then set up the path to zlib 1.2.3 via:

```
    export CPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\src\zlib\1.2.3\zlib-1.2.3"
```

As per normal I then run:

```
    configure && make && make check && make install
```

The following error is then consistently generated during compiling:

```
checking CFLAGS for gcc -Wstrict-aliasing... -Wstrict-aliasing
checking CFLAGS for gcc -Warray-bounds... -Warray-bounds
checking CFLAGS making strings readonly... no, unknown
checking CFLAGS for strict prototypes... -Wstrict-prototypes
checking for pkg-config... no
configure: warning: pkgconfigdir=C:/mingw/lib/pkgconfig (see config.log)
configure: perhaps: make install pkgconfigdir=/
configure: warning: aclocaldir=C:/mingw/share/aclocal (see config.log)
configure: perhaps: make install aclocaldir=/mingw/share/aclocal
C:\MinGW\bin\sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `C'
configure: creating ./config.status
C:\MinGW\bin\sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `C'
config.status: creating Makefile
gawk: ./confjLOGyR/subs.awk:73: S["CFLAGS"]="   -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wmissing-declarations -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror-implicit-function-declarat"\
gawk: ./confjLOGyR/subs.awk:73:                                                                                                                                                                   ^ backslash not last character on line
C:\MinGW\bin\sed.exe: couldn't write 1 item to stdout: Invalid argument
config.status: error: could not create Makefile
C:\MinGW\bin\sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `C'
C:\MinGW\bin\sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `C'
```

I have tried the guide "Compiling zziplib with MinGW" from: http://itsacleanmachine.blogspot.com/2012/03/compiling-zziplib-with-mingw.html
But unfortunately the error persists. New to compiling in general so excuse my ignorance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drives letters, as `C:/mingw/lib/pkgconfig`, do not exist in Unix-like
OSes and the drive-letter syntax `C:...` will confuse Unix tools, as you
are seeing. Build the package within a Unix-like environment (`MSYS2`,`cygwin`)
making use only of valid Unix-style paths in that environment.

Comment: Sorry, I'd need to be at your machine to get any further ;)

Comment: @MikeKinghan thanks for the reply. I have now installed zlib 1.2.3 in the home directory of msys and repeated the above with:`export  CPATH=/home/Jacques/GnuWin32/src/zlib/1.2.3/zlib-1.2.3`, however still getting the same error. I have also run: `mount c:/mingw /mingw`. I am using the default make files shipped with the library and there is no where that I have explicitly specified windows like paths. Any ideas?